# $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ Derived sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm trying to construct a countable compact metric space such that for all $n$, its nth derived set is non-empty.

My attempt: Let $A = \{0\} \cup \left\{\frac{1}{n}: n \geq 2\right\}$. Consider $$A_1 = A \cup \left\{\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{k}\left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}\right): k \geq 2\right\}.$$
I'm basically constructing a sequence that approaches each point in $A$ from the right. Repeat this process; for $i \in \mathbb{N}$, $A_{i+1}$ is the union of $A_i$ along with all the sequences that approach each point in $A_i$ from the right. However, $\bigcup_{ i \geq 1}A_i$ is not closed in this case.

Is there any hint or suggestion?

Comment: If you just need the $n$-the derived set to be non-empty for a fixed $n$, look at the set $A_n$ constructed in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990065/iteration-of-derived-sets/990805#990805) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3761478/construct-a-set-of-the-real-line-such-that-nth-derived-set-is-empty/3761512#3761512).

Comment: I've looked at them before posting. However, I'm trying to find a countable compact  metric space  $A $ such that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $A^{(n)} \neq \emptyset$. Is there any suggestion? Thank you!

Comment: Are you at all familiar with infinite ordinal numbers?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not.

Comment: See the set ${E_2}$ in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/336929/13130). Something similar to $E_2 \cup \{2\}$ will work. (You'll need to include right limiting endpoints at each construction stage leading up to this, I think, to ensure the set is closed.)